# A question about independence

Tags: probability

Three random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and $X$ and $Z$ are independent, will  $X$ and $(Y,Z)$ be independent?
If not, what some minimal condition to be added will make it true?

Thanks!